# Identify a story about wireless power killing insects

Tags: story-identification

Back when I was in school (sometime between 1990 and 1997) I remember reading a excerpt from a story about near-future humans developing wireless power technology.  The power was sent down to Earth via a web of satellites orbiting the planet.  The moment the satellites are activated the power almost immediately kills all the insect life on the planet (I remember the story saying that insects "popped" like tiny water balloons), collapsing the entire food web of the planet.

Unfortunately the excerpt ended well before anything was resolved, and I don't remember the name of the story.  If anyone can help me find this story so I can finally get some closure on this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Reminds me a little of David Kagan's [*Sunstroke,*](http://www.amazon.com/Sunstroke-David-Kagan/dp/1557738548/ref=tmm_pap_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=) a not-too-bad techno-thriller about one possible risk of shooting a microwave laser at the Earth.

Comment: "Back when [you] were in school"? Hmm. Your profile has your age at 36, so I guess that means you read it sometime between 1985 and 1997?

Comment: That would be correct, though probably the later half of that range.  If it helps at all, I think the excerpt was used as part of a standardized test of some sort to try and gauge the ability to infer information.

Comment: Can you add that timeframe into the title and body of the question? And the standardized test possibility into the body?